# Eclipse JPA Facet reporting invalid query

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I am using Eclipse Kepler SR1 and the JPA facet keeps on telling me one of my queries is invalid:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l FROM Lobby l JOIN l.slots s WHERE s.id != 'l'
```

The identification variable '!=' is not defined in the FROM clause.
The expression is not a valid conditional expression.

It works when i change it to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l FROM Lobby l JOIN l.slots s WHERE s.id = 'l'
```

Anything wrong with my join syntax or just a bug of the JPA facet? Hibernate reports no error.

greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<>` instead of `!=` since `!=` is not a valid [JPQL operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_operators):

```
SELECT DISTINCT l FROM Lobby l JOIN l.slots s WHERE s.id <> 'l'
```

Comment: Ah silly me...seems like hibernate supports the != but jpa spec doesn't. Simple but it was bugging me. Thanks!